# Where is @Twig defined in symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, defined

I am new to symfony.While going through an error template I came across value a value like

@Twig/Exception/traces_text.html.twig

Just wanted to know where is @Twig defined in symfony framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just google `twig traces_text.html.twig` and you'll see the file here: https://github.com/symfony/twig-bundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Exception/traces_text.html.twig

**symfony/twig-bundle/Resources/views/Exception/traces_text.html.twig**

Or use your IDE and search the `vendor/` folder for the `traces_text.html.twig` file until you find it.